# How should I build a project in native Android which has a feature like Lenskart?

Tags: android, kotlin, image-processing, firebase-mlkit

I want to just put glass over eyes.

I can use the CameraX Library for taking picture.
and take some coordinates for eyes.

Any best way to approch this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried ML Kit's [Face Detection API](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/face-detection/android)? It can detect facial "landmarks", including eyes.